# PHP/MySQL: Parse html and upload media

Tags: php, html, mysql, parsing, upload

I have a site created with PHP 4.3 and MySQL. I need a way so a client can send an HTML file to the server and have it parsed and sections inserted into the database. During parsing, any images or other media found will need to be uploaded to the server.

I am not really sure what is the best way to go about this. I was thinking of maybe using jQuery and Ajax to parse the content but what can I do to get the media?

Do you have any better suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: are you trying to implement a web crawler?

Comment: No, the HTML file is a training course that is authored in HTML with special tags for questions and other course data.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a large question. I've pointed you to some resources that might help.

For Html Parsing -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Easy way to download images and other media -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Uploading original html5 file -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Good luck

Comment: I've actually looked at most of this before and even started implementing a solution. However, I was hoping for something easier for the client. This requires the client to upload everything individually. I would like the client to just select the HTML file and based on its contents, the media is selected and uploaded accordingly.

Comment: Are the media items online or on a clients hard drive?

Comment: On the clients hard drive.

Comment: Javascript wouldn't have access to those assets, therefore jquery neither.

You would need to write it in something like java